# Ptracing Process Trees

Tags: linux, process, pid, strace, ptrace

I'm looking for code examples on how to use the Linux system call `ptrace()` to trace system calls of a process **and** all its child, grandchild, etc processes. Similar to the behaviour of `strace` when it is fed the fork flag `-f`.

I'm aware of the alternative of looking into the sources of strace but I'm asking for a clean tutorial first in the hopes of getting a more isolated explanation.

I'm gonna use this to implement a fast generic system call memoizer similar to https://github.com/nordlow/strace-memoize but written in a compiled language. My current code examples I want to extend with this logic is my fork of ministrace at https://github.com/nordlow/ministrace/blob/master/ministrace.c

Answer (score 1):

RTFM `PTRACE_SETOPTIONS` with the `PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE`, `PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK` and `PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK` flags. In a nutshell, if you set it on a process, any time it creates children, those will automatically be traced as well.